# In VS2010, is there a way to automatically close Server Explorer connections to Database pre-Execute/Debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process, build-automation

When I run my application, it drops and re-creates a database.

Between runs, I typically use the VS2010 server explorer view to look at various database objects.

If I forget to right-click the node in the Server explorer and explicitly close the connection, then when I run, the drop/recreate hangs for a while (at which time I can race the timeout and go close the connection if I feel like it) and then throws an exception.  This is all fine and expected.

Is there any known mechanism/facility in VS2010 that can help be get the behavior of the pre-execute step that closes the connection for me?

[image]